# FoxPro 'Zipped' backup

Tags: backup, foxpro

I have, what I believe to be, a FoxPro Backup file with file extension .02A.
The first seven characters of this 150MB file are ' !Pƒõ' in hex: 1F A0 21 50 83 9D F5.

Who knows what kind of file this is exactly and how do I get to the contents?

Comment: It's not anything that FoxPro or Visual FoxPro creates.

Answer (score 2):

1F A0

Is associated with .tar based zip files as found at
[Wikipedia List of file signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)